# Advanced Pricing "Cost" attribute is missing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.5

[image]

That is how the advanced pricing page is supposed to look like.  Mine looks exactly the same except the "Cost" field is missing.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Also, does this cost field actually have any functionality?  I'm looking to calculate prices based on my cost.  Is that possible in Vanilla Magento 2.1?

Thanks

Comment: To make it visible please enable MAP feature in System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Minimum Advertised Price

Comment: It is enabled, but there is still nothing there.  MSRP and Display actual Price are, just not cost.